# TOP N/% Chart in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a query which currently pulls back a list of sales by sales person throughout a particular financial year. This has been deployed in SSRS; I would now like to add a chart that graphs these sales, but I want to restrict the chart to the TOP N sales (by revenue) as there are over 10,000 sales people.

I would prefer not to have to change my query or result set.

Graph currently looks like this:

[image]

Current configuration of graph:
[image]

Current query looks like this:

```
SELECT
EMPD.emp_name,
SUM(ISNULL(CID.menu_item_sales_amount,0)) AS [Amount]


FROM ig_Business..Check_Item_Detail CID (NOLOCK) -- sum of sales by emp id
JOIN ig_Transaction..Transaction_Master TM (NOLOCK) on tm.transaction_data_id = cid.transaction_data_id AND tm.ent_id = 1 -- ent_id 1 equals not test data
JOIN ig_business..Check_Sales_Detail CSD (NOLOCK) ON CSD.transaction_data_id = CID.transaction_data_id -- tender period is stored here
JOIN ig_Dimension..Employee_Dimension EMPD (NOLOCK) ON CID.emp_dim_id = EMPD.emp_dim_id -- so we can get employee name
JOIN ig_Dimension..Menu_Item_Dimension MID (NOLOCK) on MID.menu_item_dim_id = CID.menu_item_dim_id and MID.ent_id = 1
JOIN ig_Dimension..Check_Type_Dimension CTD (NOLOCK) on CTD.check_type_dim_id = CSD.check_type_dim_id

/* Date Range Changed Below */
WHERE ( 
tm.updated_date_time BETWEEN @startdatecast AND @enddatecast
)
AND MID.report_category_id in (2,25,73,33,81,84,1,14)
AND CID.menu_item_status = 0
AND CTD.check_type_id in (1,5,7,10,9,12,13,14,15,16,17,20,21,22,23,24,25,27,28,29,30,31,33,34)
AND EMPD.emp_name NOT IN ('REUSE, REUSE','Trial3, Test','Trial, Trial','Test, Trial')

GROUP BY EMPD.emp_name
ORDER by [Amount] DESC,EMPD.emp_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a filter to the category group, an example would be:

```
expression = [sum(Amount)]
operator = Top N
Value = 10
```